# Error occurred when I install Gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite, gitlab

I successfully download Gitolite file based on  [link](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html#migr) instruction.. When I try to run gitolite/install -ln I get the following error:

---

```
[root@Project1-CO mygit]# gitolite/install -ln
error: unknown option `dirty=-dt'
usage: git describe [options] <committish>*

--contains            find the tag that comes after the commit
--debug               debug search strategy on stderr
--all                 use any ref in .git/refs
--tags                use any tag in .git/refs/tags
--long                always use long format
--abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display SHA-1s
--exact-match         only output exact matches
--candidates <n>      consider <n> most recent tags (default: 10)
--match <pattern>     only consider tags matching <pattern>
--always              show abbreviated commit object as fallback
```

---

Please help me out, what the actual problem is??? I am using git 1.6.5, Operating system Linux (32 -bit) (fedora - 17).

Comment: what your `git version` says?

Comment: As I told you, give us *all* the details: OS, version of the OS, version of git, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your git - it is most likely too old. In more recent git versions `git describe` [supports option --dirty](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) that you are missing.

According to [gitolite site](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html#req), git must be at least version 1.6.6.
I would recommend 1.7.11 or 1.8.

Comment: It depends on your OS. On Ubuntu, simply using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git-core` may work at once.

Comment: I am using fedora, when i used the command it shows sudo: apt-get: command not found error

Comment: On fedora, try using `yum install git-core`. But, if your Fedora is too old (older than Fedora 14 I think) this may not help - you may need to find 3rd party repository, upgrade the OS or install git from source